# Adding console output into cucumber html report

Tags: ruby, testing, automated-tests, cucumber, bdd

I have helper `method.rb` file which is under `features/util/service/` directory. This helper class' methods are logging information into the console by `puts` method during the test execution.

The problem is that the logs in the helper class are not shown in the cucumber HTML report. However, the logs in the `features/step_definitions/` directory are shown in the cucumber HTML report.

The question is, how to add log information which is logging by `puts` command under cucumber default `/feature` directory into the cucumber HTML report?

Example console logs which I copied from the IDE. I just want to see logs from `service_post requested url` to `current_balance: 403338.07`.

```
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/bundle exec /usr/local/opt/ruby/bin/ruby -EUTF-8 /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/cucumber /Documents/projects/test-automation/features/test/homepage/login.feature --format Teamcity::Cucumber::Formatter --expand --name "^Successful login and logout$" --color -r features
including Capybara::DSL in the global scope is not recommended!
WARNING: The formatter Teamcity::Cucumber::Formatter is using the deprecated formatter API which will be removed in v4.0 of Cucumber.


Scenario running: Successful login and logout

Visiting url: http://url.com
service_post requested url: http://api/login/internal
service_post posted request body: {"username":"uname","password":"pass"}
service_post posted request header: {"Content-Type"=>"application/json"}
ldap_cookie: auth_cookie=nCzG...
User current_balance: 403338.07
Tags: @@done, @@smoke

Logging Seller ==> Username: e... ==> Cookie: auth_cookie=tBDU...

PASSED ==> Feature: Homepage login scenarios => Scenario: Successful_login_and_logout

[INFO] - [2020-03-26 14:45:38 +0300] - visit homepage
[INFO] - [2020-03-26 14:45:48 +0300] - login
[INFO] - [2020-03-26 14:45:54 +0300] - logout
1 scenario (1 passed)
3 steps (3 passed)
0m22.309s
Process finished with exit code 0
```

[image: Example report]